# Login form validation Code Igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation, authentication

**My form:**

```
<?php
          echo validation_errors(); 
                        $clientLoginFormAttr = array('id'=>'clientLogin');
                        echo form_open('clientLogin',$clientLoginFormAttr);

                        ## generate field attributes
                        $userNameInput=array(
                            'type' =>'text',
                            'id' => 'clientLogin',
                            'name' => 'clientUsername',
                            'maxlength' => '10',
                            'size' => '20'
                        );
                       $passwordInput=array(
                           'type'=>'password',
                           'id'=>'clientLogin',
                           'name'=>'clientPass',
                           'maxlength'=>'10',
                           'size'=>'20'
                       );
                       $submitBtn=array(
                           'type'=>'submit',
                           'id'=>'submit',
                           'value'=>'',
                           'name'=>'sendLogon'
                       );
                       ## generate actual <input> fields
                       echo '<label>Username:</label>';
                       echo form_input($userNameInput);
                       echo '<label>Password:</label>';
                       echo form_input($passwordInput);
                       echo form_submit($submitBtn);  
                    ?>
```

I want to use the *clientLogin* controller which is in (controllers/pages/hndl/clientLogin.php)

*clientLogin* controller contains:

```
<?php
class Clientlogin extends CI_Controller{

    function index(){

        $this->load->helper(array('url','form'));
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $loginValidation = array(
          array(
              'field'=>'clientUsername',
              'rules'=>'required|min_length[1]|max_length[10]'
          ),  
          array(
              'field'=>'clientPass',
              'rules'=>'required|min_length[1]|max_length[10]'  
          )  
        );

        $this->form_validation->set_rules($loginValidation);

    }
}

?>
```

When I visit my homepage (called homepage.php) set as default view to load, and press the SUBMIT button, it gives me the ERROR-404 OBJECT NOT FOUND. It goes to the path:

```
http://localhost/Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/website/homepage.php/clientLogin
```

What am I doing wrong here? I'm simply trying to use the clientLogin controller to control the form being submitted from homepage.php view. Thanks

Comment: Do you get a 404 if you go to this address... `http://localhost/Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/website/homepage.php/clientLogin/index`   Also maybe try adding a view or even a simple `echo 'hello';` after your `form_validation->set_rules` just to make sure that the route is working

Comment: I do get a 404 if i visit that.

Comment: Ah I see. If TheShiftExchange's answer doesn't work then there's something not right. Try going to this address... `http://localhost/Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/website/homepage.php/pages/hndl/clientLogin`  You need to remember that your clientLogin controller's not in the same directory as your homepage/index controller.

Comment: What is your base_url set to?

Comment: Base_url = /Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/website/

Comment: and what is your DOCUMENT ROOT?

Comment: where is this set? If you mean, my "root", that is .../Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/

Comment: It will be under the file at your installation directory something like `c:/xampp/apache/conf/httpd.conf` check for `DocumentRoot` directive in this file

Comment: DocumentRoot "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs"

Comment: btw your base url should be preceded with http, could be something like `http://localhost/Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/website/`

Comment: DocumentRoot should be directing to the root directory that holds your website.. could be something like: `C:/xampp/htdocs`

Comment: DocumentRoot in httpd.conf = /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs, the document root of my site is localhost/website

Comment: website, is within htdocs. so its like http://localhost/website

Comment: check the answer below - I guess problem lies with your document root and base_url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it is something with your root directories and base_url.

Your website should be at:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\website
```

then your DocumentRoot should be set to:

```
C:/xampp/htdocs
```

and your base_url under your codeigniter's config/config.php should be set to:

```
http://localhost/website/
```

then your form should be set to:

```
echo form_open('pages/hndl/clientLogin',$clientLoginFormAttr);
```

That is what I can think/assume your case is?

Comment: I've created other controller/views though... like aboutus.php (controller) , aboutus.php (view) and they are working fine

Comment: This is the first time though I'm trying to call a controller from a controller e.g. the homepage.php (controller) login form calling the clientlogin (controller) [on submit] of the form

Comment: what is the url you use to access aboutus.php?

Comment: is it possible to call a CONTROLLER from a CONTROLLER ?

Comment: at a time only single controller will be called I believe.. For example I have controller called USER and then have other functions inside this controller like add, delete, edit.. their URL will be User/add, User/delete, User/edit respectively.. So only one controller can be called

Comment: How do I achieve this then? If I have homepage.php (controller) which has a login form with fields username and password. What should the ACTION attribute be of the form that is ?

Comment: are you able to see the form at all? I mean simple form page? what is the url for that?

Comment: http://localhost/website/    loads the homepage (controller). This loads everything fine with the login inputs... but when I press ENTER it tries to load clientlogin @ http://localhost/Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/website/homepage.php/pages/hndl/clientlogin  ... even though the path on the webserver is: http://localhost/website/homepage.php/pages/hndl/clientlogin (which returns a err-404)

Comment: ok remove the `form_open` tag and try: `<form action='http://localhost/website/homepage.php/pages/hndl/clientlogin' method='post'>` .... ... .... </form>

Comment: sorry dude.. can't see the reason here.. may be someone else could help.. I am sorry

Answer (score 0):

try changing

```
echo form_open('clientLogin',$clientLoginFormAttr);
```

to

```
echo form_open('pages/hndl/clientLogin',$clientLoginFormAttr);
```

Comment: Please see my thoughts in my question, what do you think